# Laravel Admin - regenerate admin after database change

Tags: php, laravel, database, seeding, laravel-admin

I am developing a Laravel application, and I use Laravel-Admin (https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/) for an admin panel. It worked well, but after I changed the database for the application, I do not know how can I regenerate admin user for the application.

I tried seeding the database but I have not found any default seeders in DatabaseSeeder.php, after I tried putting this into my DatabaseSeeder.php file:

```
Encore\Admin\Auth\Database\Administrator\Administrator::create([
     'username' => 'admin',
     'password' => bcrypt('password'),
     'name'     => 'Administrator',
]);
```

The seeding went well, the administrator user was generated, but after logging in to the admin panel, it gave me an error: 'Permission denied'.

I have also tried the command written in the documentation:  `php artisan admin:create-user` , but it gives me this error: Choice question must have at least 1 choice available.

Comment: And what can we do with this info? What is `Administrator` model/class? Are you using a package for permissions? What is the important part for being an admin, just using `Administrator`? What do you mean when you say "after I changed the database i do not know how can I regenerate admin user", how was it done the first time? Add this basic info please

Comment: your changes must reflect on the code that's why you can't use the  `admin:create-user`to create a admin user